# How to properly replace components of laptop which has non-removable battery?

Tags: laptop, battery

If I would use laptop with removable battery, then I need to remove battery before replace some components (HDD, RAM) of laptop (in order to remove charge). But what should I do in case of laptop with non-removable battery ? Should I discharge the battery ?

Comment: What model laptop?

Comment: @N. Greene I wanna know common recommendations, not for specific model

Comment: @YaH: Depends entirely on if the laptop allows you to disconnect the battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're changing components such as HDD/RAM, you should be safe to do so without removing the battery on a laptop that has the battery sealed inside of the chassis. BUT, you DO need to take extra precaution to not touch any electrical contacts or components on the computer when doing these replacements, as they may cause injury to you and/or damage to the laptop.

If you are changing out a keyboard, screen, track pad, etc... on a laptop without a removable battery, you should be able to disconnect the internal battery connector since you will already have the chassis apart for this repair.